# Unable to validate complete JSON schema using tv4

Tags: arrays, api, testing, automated-tests, postman

Total newb here.

I'm wondering if someone can help because i'm at a loss! I'm trying to assert that the response from a GET API Call meets this monster schema set - Using console.log() it looks like each of the properties is accessed successfully and if i change the object type the test will fail as i'd expect.

Working down the schema - If i try and change a property in the data array i.e from string to boolean the test will still pass although it doesn't meet the required schema i've defined,

Any guidance is massively appreciated!

```js
//Test the schema is valid
const schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "current_page": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "data": {
            "type": "array",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "first_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "last_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "telephone": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "postcode": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "date_of_birth": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "profession": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "time_served": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "national_insurance_number": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "employer": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lco_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "company_employed": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "company_employed_email": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "company_employed_telephone": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "company_employed_address": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "apprentice": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "apprentice_trade": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "apprentice_course": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "apprentice_started_at": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "apprentice_ended_at": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "work_experience": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "work_experience_trade": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "work_experience_education": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "work_experience_started_at": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "work_experience_ended_at": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "nvq": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "nvq_trade": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "nvq_education": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "nvq_started_at": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "nvq_ended_at": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "unemployed": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "unemployed_months": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "company_employed_postcode": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "partner_relationship": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "self_partner_relationship": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "emergency_contact_first_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "emergency_contact_last_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "emergency_contact_telephone": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "enrollment_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "created_at": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "updated_at": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "mode_of_travel": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "driver_or_passenger": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "fuel_type": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "engine_capacity": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "rtw_declaration": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "rtw_proof1_upload_id": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "rtw_proof2_upload_id": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "card_type": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "gender": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "self_gender": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "marital_status": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "disability_act": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "disability_description": {
                    "type": "null"
                },
                "ethnic_origin": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "religion": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "nationality": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "sexual_orient": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "checked_membership": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "training_checked": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "enrollment": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "inducted": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "user_id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "created_at": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "updated_at": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "expiry_date": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "user": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "email": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "role": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "created_at": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "updated_at": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "state": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "last_login_at": {
                                    "type": "null"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "id",
                                "email",
                                "role",
                                "created_at",
                                "updated_at",
                                "state",
                                "last_login_at"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "id",
                        "inducted",
                        "user_id",
                        "created_at",
                        "updated_at",
                        "expiry_date",
                        "user"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "id",
                "first_name",
                "last_name",
                "telephone",
                "postcode",
                "date_of_birth",
                "profession",
                "time_served",
                "national_insurance_number",
                "employer",
                "lco_id",
                "company_employed",
                "company_employed_email",
                "company_employed_telephone",
                "company_employed_address",
                "apprentice",
                "apprentice_trade",
                "apprentice_course",
                "apprentice_started_at",
                "apprentice_ended_at",
                "work_experience",
                "work_experience_trade",
                "work_experience_education",
                "work_experience_started_at",
                "work_experience_ended_at",
                "nvq",
                "nvq_trade",
                "nvq_education",
                "nvq_started_at",
                "nvq_ended_at",
                "unemployed",
                "unemployed_months",
                "company_employed_postcode",
                "partner_relationship",
                "self_partner_relationship",
                "emergency_contact_first_name",
                "emergency_contact_last_name",
                "emergency_contact_telephone",
                "enrollment_id",
                "created_at",
                "updated_at",
                "mode_of_travel",
                "driver_or_passenger",
                "fuel_type",
                "engine_capacity",
                "rtw_declaration",
                "rtw_proof1_upload_id",
                "rtw_proof2_upload_id",
                "card_type",
                "gender",
                "self_gender",
                "marital_status",
                "disability_act",
                "disability_description",
                "ethnic_origin",
                "religion",
                "nationality",
                "sexual_orient",
                "checked_membership",
                "training_checked",
                "enrollment",
            ]
        },
    }
}

// Use tiny validator to validate the results - Error if there are additional properties, and check recursion.

pm.test("Validate schema contains the relevant details", () => {
    tv4.validateMultiple(jsonData, schema, true, true);
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

    // Log all errors to the console 
    var validationResult = tv4.validateMultiple(jsonData, schema, true, true);
    for (var i = 0; i < validationResult.errors.length; i++) {
        console.log("path :" + validationResult.errors[i].dataPath + " message :" + validationResult.errors[i].message);
    }

});
```

Comment: Could you also post the response please or at least the structure of it if it contains sensitive information. Postman include AJV which might be better here so you would just need to have `pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema)` in your test and not all the rest.

Comment: how does a data array has properties ? is it array of objects with that property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "current_page": {
            "type": "boolean"
        }

    }
}


pm.test("Validate schema contains the relevant details", () => {

    var jsonData = { "current_page": 2 }

    // Log all errors to the console 
    var validationResult = tv4.validateMultiple(jsonData, schema, true, true);
    validationResult.valid ? null : console.log(JSON.stringify(validationResult, null, 2))
    pm.expect(validationResult.valid, JSON.stringify(validationResult, null, 2)).to.be.true


});
```

you don't have expect to assert it that's why it passes always , also as Danny mentioned use

```
const schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "current_page": {
            "type": "boolean"
        }

    }
}


pm.test("Validate schema contains the relevant details", () => {

var jsonData = { "current_page": 2 }

pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema)

});
```

And for array you should use items instead of property:

```
const schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required":["id","name"]
            }
        }
    }
}
pm.test("Validate schema contains the relevant details", () => {

    var jsonData = { "data": [{ "id": 2,"name":"test" }] }
    // Log all errors to the console 
    var validationResult = tv4.validateMultiple(jsonData, schema, true, true);
    validationResult.valid ? null : console.log(JSON.stringify(validationResult, null, 2))
    pm.expect(validationResult.valid, JSON.stringify(validationResult, null, 2)).to.be.true


});
```

you can create schema with so much ease using :

https://www.jsonschema.net/login